# В чем разница между *$("div:not(.class1)")* и *$("div").not(".class1")*?

Tags: jquery

Привет.

Вопрос по jQuery. Не понимаю одну штуку.

Есть, например, *CSS* псевдокласс `:not(селектор)`, имеется и аналогичная функция jquery `not(селектор)`. Зачем дублировать?

Второй пример - есть jquery псевдокласс `:has(селектор)`, а есть и аналогичная функция jquery `has()`. Таких примеров дублирования много. Не понимаю, зачем дублировать?

**Пример.** В чем разница между `$("div:not(.class1)")` и `$("div").not(".class1")`?

Первый вариант - это "выбери все дивы, у которых класс НЕ является `class1`".
 Второй вариант - это "выбери все дивы, потом отбери из них те, у которых класс НЕ является `class1`"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Из [рус.док.](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%98%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B8%D0%B7_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85_%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2)

> Метод .not() выполняет то же самое, что и рассматриваемый селектор
>   (:not), и чаще всего, при его использовании, код получается более
>   читаемым, чем при использовании селектора :not().

Из примеров:

```js
$("div")
  .not(".class1")
  .css({'background-color': 'red'});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div>item1</div>
<div class="class1">item2</div>
<div>item3</div>
```

**И**

```js
$("div:not(.class1)").css({'background-color': 'red'});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div>item1</div>
<div class="class1">item2</div>
<div>item3</div>
```

Видно, что нет разницы. Используйте, то что по душе.

**P.S:** Обратите внимание на пример @Anton Shchyrov.

```js
$("div")
  .css({'background-color': 'red'})
  .not(".class1")
  .css({'background-color': 'transparent'});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div>item1</div>
<div class="class1">item2</div>
<div>item3</div>
```

Результат исключения уже иной.

Comment: естественно результат будет другой, ведь передаются другие параметры. Странно было бы ожидать тот же результат.

Comment: "неа, не будет. Так в чем разница-то? – Grundy 28 минут назад" не обосновал

Comment: а что обосновывать? что приведена левая строка кода и неизвестно что хотел сказать ее автор? Так это очевидно

Comment: @Grundy, да автор ответа, вроде, расшифровал что имел ввиду. Одно из, возможно полезных, применений. Ну да ладно.

Comment: вообще говоря - нет. он кинул кусок кода, написал что делает этот кусок. но никак не обозначил как это относится к заданному вопросу

Comment: Ну да, это есть, хотя пример интересный, но это для меня)

Answer (score 1):

А если так, понятнее будет?

```
$("div").css({'background-color': "red"}).not(".class1").css({'border': "1px"})
```

выбрать все дивы, покрасить в красный, потом отбросить все с классом и нарисовать рамку

Comment: неа, не будет. Так в чем разница-то?

Comment: @Grundy, в данном случае почему не будет? `$("div")
  .css({'background-color': 'red'})
  .not(".class1")
  .css({'background-color': 'transparent'});` И `$("div:not(.class1)").css({'background-color': 'red'});` - разный результат будет.

Comment: соображения есть такие: насколько я понимаю, выборку можно только СУЗИТЬ фильтром. расширить выборку обратно нельзя - надо заново делать выборку. если задача стоит сделать выборку, что-то с ней сделать, потом сузить и что-то опять сделать, то вариант $("div")..(функция)....not(".class1")..(функция)... подходит лучше, так как он делает только 1 выборку. если писать $("div:not(.class1)")...(функции)... , а потом $("div")....(функции)... , то тут получается 2 выборки. то есть, браузер 2 раза выбирает, а это лишние затраты вычислительные. то есть, какой вариант использовать лучше-зависит от задачи

Comment: Я же написал > выбрать все дивы, покрасить в красный, потом отбросить все с классом и нарисовать рамку. Т.е. вначале, что-то сделать с общим набором, а потом отфильтровать этот набор

Comment: Можно и расширить `$('div').add('p')`

Comment: По идее, это - $("div:not('.class1')").add("div.class1").css({'background-color': "red"}).not(".class1").css({'border': "1px"})  - отработает так же, как  и ваш вариант - $("div").css({'background-color': "red"}).not(".class1").css({'border': "1px"}). Но ваш вариант ЛЕГЧЕ прочитать и понять. значит, какой вариант использовать - зависит от того, какой вариант получится более читаемый

Comment: @Dimon не совсем понял зачем вы вначале выбираете дивы без класса, а потом добавляете класс, чтобы потом опять убрать класс?

Comment: @Dimon, а что вот это такое `.add("div.class1")` что тут происходит у Вас?) просто интересно, не подумайте ничего)

Comment: @ElenaSemenchenko, вообще, это [`функция add`](https://api.jquery.com/add/), но в комментарии выше нет смысла в ее использовании

Comment: .add("div") - да функция, а .add("div.class1") непонятное что-то, на сколько я знаю. Сразу присвоить класс нельзя же или можно? У меня ошибку выдает.

Comment: @ElenaSemenchenko, _add_ это функция принимающая селектор и добавляющая результат выборки к уже существующему набору, в комментарии выше сначала выбрали дивы без класс, затем добавили к ним дивы с классом. `add` это не `addClass` она ничего не делает с выбранными элементами

Comment: Теперь поняла, спасибо.

Comment: я просто привел ДВА способа сделать одно и то же