# Как добавить список классов и тегов, на которые не распространяется действие

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как добавить правило, в котором будут перечислены список классов и тегов, на которые скрипт не должен реагировать?

Например, вот скрипт:

```
$('a[title]').each(function() {
  if (this.title) {
    $(this).addClass('yjsg-tip-top').attr('data-yjsg-tip', this.title);
    $(this).removeAttr('title');
  }
});
```

В нем нужно запретить срабатывание на `div.top_menu`, `#holder` и `.newclass`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вариант с `.not()`:

```js
$('a[title]').not('div.top_menu a, #holder a, .newclass a').each(function() {
  if (this.title) {
    $(this).addClass('yjsg-tip-top').attr('data-yjsg-tip', this.title);
    $(this).removeAttr('title');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" title="123">Ссылка с title</a><br />
<a href="#">Ссылка без title</a>
<div class="top_menu"><a href="#" title="123">Ссылка в блоке с классом top_menu</a></div>
<p class="newclass"><a href="#" title="123">Ссылка в элементе с классом newclass</a></p>
<div id="holder"><a href="#" title="123">Ссылка в блоке с идентификатором holder</a></div>
```

Вариант с `:not()`:

```js
$('a[title]:not(div.top_menu a, #holder a, .newclass a)').each(function() {
  if (this.title) {
    $(this).addClass('yjsg-tip-top').attr('data-yjsg-tip', this.title);
    $(this).removeAttr('title');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" title="123">Ссылка с title</a><br />
<a href="#">Ссылка без title</a>
<div class="top_menu"><a href="#" title="123">Ссылка в блоке с классом top_menu</a></div>
<p class="newclass"><a href="#" title="123">Ссылка в элементе с классом newclass</a></p>
<div id="holder"><a href="#" title="123">Ссылка в блоке с идентификатором holder</a></div>
```

Comment: @Slava да, оба вариант равнозначны, только с .not() [код получается более читаемым](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%98%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B8%D0%B7_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85_%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2). Вот в [этом примере](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/573234/209956) можно увидеть еще одно приемущество .not()

Comment: Большое спасибо за оперативные ответы, рабочие решения и полезные ссылки! Мне с .not() тоже больше нравится (понятнее))